# Code is hanging, infinite loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write some python code to extract data. It is almost correct but it seems to hang towards the end of making the first file. Is there an infinite loop somewhere?

```
train = open('mp_crf_train.txt', 'r')
lines = train.readlines()
number = 0

for i in lines:
    filename = str(number) + ".txt"
    outfile = open(filename,"w")
    lst = i.split(' ')
    x=1
    #while x < len(lst):
    for word in lst:
        if '<' in word and '/' not in word:
            sword = word[1:len(word)-1]
            close = '</'+ sword + '>'
            while lst[x] != close:
                    outfile.write(lst[x])
                    outfile.write('  ')
                    outfile.write(sword)
                    outfile.write('\n')
                    if x!=len(lst)-1:
                       x=x+1
            x=x+1
    number = number+1
```

Comment: What if that `while` loop never finds `close`?

Comment: And what happens if you have nested tags?

Comment: You don't have to ask us if you have an infinite loop. Print some debug statements and you'll find out. I'd recommend that you learn how to debug in general as well.

Comment: It should though! close is supposed to be exactly like the last member if the list. Is list[x] never finding the end?

Comment: @KEYSER Hung my debugger as well...

Comment: @user2951046 don't really on "is supposed to be". *check it*.

Comment: Seems pretty clear that I'm trying to force that last comparison to happen to take me out of the while loop. Ive checked both values and they are identical. I still don't get why that while statement gets by passed.

Comment: Your `x` logic doesn't make sense. Are you expecting the `for` loop to continue from where `x` left off? It won't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the makings of an infinite loop. If you reach the end of `lst` without finding `close` you're in an infinite loop since you're guarding against incrementing x. If you *were* getting an index error (likely)- your fix of checking x against the length is what caused the infinite loop.

```
        while lst[x] != close:
                ...
                if x!=len(lst)-1:
                   x=x+1
```

What you should probably use is

```
        while x<len(lst) and lst[x] != close:
                ...
                x=x+1
```

or since you don't seem to need `x`

```
        for item in lst:
            if item == close:
                break
            ...
```

If you need to keep track of `x`

```
        for x, item in enumerate(lst):
            if item == close:
                break
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Used your first suggestion.

Comment: @user2951046 If the answer of gnibbler was useful for you, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Um, yes.  How do you know that this loop

```
        while lst[x] != close:
```

will ever end?  Is `close` necessarily in `list`?  What about whitespace (I presume this is HTML or something whitespace ignorant)?  You are assuming that the close brace is exactly of the form `'</'+ sword + '>'`

Comment: HTML isn't a regular language, so suggesting that the OP try to use a regex to parse it is just cruel.

Answer (score 1):

The only place that this can become an infinite loop is here:

```
while lst[x] != close:
```

which will be infinte if `lst[x]` is *never* `close`. Do a `print(lst[x])` at every iteration (or just check the relvant lines in your `outfile`), and compare it against what you expect - there is likely a trivial difference that you have missed.